# How to make Scrollable List area in a specific div in body (Onsen-UI)

Tags: list, cordova, scroll, onsen-ui

I am making phonegap application using Onsen-UI. In that,I made a signup page. Now whenever I am trying to scroll the screen, whole body of page is scrolling. I want a particular division in a body that should scroll only. I have app Logo above the signup page and Logo is in the body part. So that shouldn't be scrolled. Only  List div should be scrolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the `<ons-scroller>` directive:

```
<ons-scroller style="height: 200px">
   <p>I am scrollable</p>
</ons-scroller>
```

I made a simple example: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/dPeKOB

Comment: I think your given example is not related to this topic.

Comment: Then please be more specific in your question because it sounds like you want to make a specific area scrollable. Also please post your code and explain what's wrong.

Comment: I just realized I accidentally removed the example. I've restored it now. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius how can I keep a static area on top of the page (below the toolbar) and only allow a list on the bottom of the page to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

This option works to me:

```
<ons-page>
  Toolbar here

  <div class="background"></div>

  <div class="content">
    Scrollable content here
  </div>

  Fixed content here
</ons-page>
```

from: https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-page.html